# Android fill table dynamical with layout

Tags: android

I try to fill a table on Android with predefined Row- and Field-Layouts. The result should be a 6x5 (or 6x4) Table with only coloured fields, that have a black border.

So i created the activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="abc" />
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/beertable">
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the Row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</TableRow>
```

And here the field layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dip"
    android:background="#ffc35a"
    android:layout_margin="1dip">
</View>
```

In my Activity i tried a for-loop to insert rows and fields, but when I test this code, i only see the text "abc" and then the rest of the screen is in the color of the fields. There are no borders, and i cant see where the table starts and stops.

```
public class WG extends Activity {    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_wg);
        TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.beertable);

        TableRow ll;
        View beerField;

        for(int i = 0;i<6;i++)
        {
            ll = (TableRow) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.wg_beer_row, null);
            table.addView(ll);
            for(int a=0;a<5;a++)
            {
                beerField = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.wg_beer_field, null);
                ll.addView(beerField);
            }   

        }    
    }
}
```

May someone show me the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> May someone show me the mistake?

Give your inflated view the proper `LayoutParams`:

```
ll = (TableRow) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.wg_beer_row, table, false);
```

and:

```
beerField = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.wg_beer_field, ll, false);
```